# Listas anidadas en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postgresql

Estoy trabajando sobre laravel 5.5

Tengo estas dos listas:

1- La primera es una lista de los sistemas operativos

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_so', 'Sistema Operativo', App\SistemasOperativos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

2- La segunda, deberia listar las versiones de acuerdo al sistema operativo

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_version', 
               'Version S.O:', 
                App\SoVersiones::select(DB::raw("version AS version"), "id","id_so")->where('id', '=', 1)-> pluck('version', 'id','id_so')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

Llegue hasta este punto, ya que me trae las versiones porque las llame con un valor entero, Un valor quemado en el Form, Pero no encuentro la manera de traer el valor del primer mySelect para que se compare con el vlaor que estoy quemando y así, la consulta sea exitosa.

Adjunto imagen

[image: Como es el formulario]

Alguien me podria ayudar ?

Gracias por leer, feliz día.

---

EDIT:

Hola, Logre traer el valor del primer campo en una variable, pero al momento de realizar la comparación me da un error.

Primer List:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_so', 'Sistema Operativo:',$worktypes_list= App\SistemasOperativos::pluck('id', 'nombre')->toArray() , null, ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

Segundo list:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_version', 
               'Version S.O:', 
                App\SoVersiones::select(DB::raw("version AS version"), "id_so")->where('id', '=', $worktypes_list)-> pluck('version', 'id_so')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

Pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando los ID'S Podrian concordar, El problema que veo es que esta haciendo la consulta de una vez, en vez de arrojar valores en cuanto se seleccione algun valor del primer campo, Como podria corregir esto ?

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Hacer consultas del modelo en la vista está violando los principios de MVC de Laravel. Y en principio, yo te recomendaría poblar el segundo select llamando a un ajax enviando el valor que selecciona el usuario del primer select.

Comment: Me podrias explicar como ?

Entiendo que es como mandar ese valor de el primer select a un ajax verdad ? pero, despues, como hago para realizar la segunda consulta y que me pinte los resultados en esa lista...

Comment: Si, ya te escribí mi propuesta en la respuesta. chécala y si tienes duda de algo, me comentas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría poblar tu segundo select en base a lo que el usuario seleccione del primer select, ejemplo:

HTML (te lo pongo en HTML porque no me gusta laravel collective):

```
<select name="so" id="so">
   <option value="">Seleccionar sistema</option>
   {{-- Tomando en cuenta que estás enviando la variable sistemas desde tu controlador a esta vista, la cual, contiene los sistemas registrados en tu BD --}}
   @foreach($sistemas as $sistema)
      <option value="{{ $sistema->id }}">{{ $sistema->nombre }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>

<select name="version" id="version">
   <option value="">Selecciona un sistema operativo primero</option>
</select>
```

Javascript (usando jQuery):

```
var rutaConsulta = "{{ route('ruta.consulta.so') }}";
    $(document).ready(function(){
       selectChange();
    });

function selectChange(){
    $('#so').on('change', function(e){
       var idSo = $(this).val();
       ajaxSelect(idSo);
    });
}

function ajaxSelect(id){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: rutaConsulta,
            data: {id: id},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>';
            $.each(response.versiones, function(i, elem){
               html += '<option value="'+ elem.id +'">'+ elem.nombre +'</option>'
            });
            $('#version').html(html);
        }).fail(function(data) {

        });
}
```

En tu controlador PHP:

```
public function consultarVersiones(Request $request){
   $id_so = $request->id;
   $versiones = SoVersiones::where('id_so', $id_so)->get();


   $respuesta = array();
   $respuesta['versiones'] = $versiones->toArray();   
   return response()->json($respuesta);
}
```

Comment: Las estoy llamado así, Pero aun así no me lo toma:

public function create()
    {
        $sistemas = SistemasOperativos::orderBy('nombre','asc')->pluck('nombre','id');
        $versiones = SoVersiones::orderBy('version','asc')->pluck('version','id');
        return view ('admin.servidoresVistas.create', compact('sistemas','versiones'));
    }


Me da este error:

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MTI\resources\views\admin\servidoresVistas\form.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MTI\resources\views\admin\servidoresVistas\form.blade.php)

Comment: @OmarNoa ¿Cómo?, ¿podrías adjuntar lo que realizaste en una captura o en algo más claro?, por favor.

Comment: Tengo 2 problemas con el codigo que publicaste...

1- La ruta :
var rutaConsulta = "{{ route('ruta.consulta.so') }}";
 a pesar de que la tengo así.
   Route::get('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersiones'); osea, no se como llamar la ruta que tengo en el codigo que me pasaste.

Comment: @OmarNoa Explícame cuál es el problema y con gusto te ayudo

Comment: El otro problema que tengo, es cuando intento crear las listas select, con tu codigo me da problema, entonces, intente cambiar la primer lista que me pasaste por esto, y si me lo toma bien.


por esto 

{!! Form::select('nombre', $sistemas, null, ['id' => 'nombre', 'onchange'=>'mostrarVersiones()','class'=>'form-control','placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción' ])  !!}

Comment: @OmarNoa Lo siento, es que no sé cual sea el nivel de conocimiento de laravel que tengas pero creí que ya sabías que para llamar la ruta de esa manera en el ejemplo que escribí, es así: `Route::get('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersiones')->name('ruta.consulta.so');`, así le estás dando un alias a tu ruta creada, el método `route()` recibe como parámetro ese alias que le pusiste a tu ruta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82194/discussion-between-omar-noa-and-aaron-gutierrez).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar filtrando el segundo select con el id del primer select.

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_version', 
               'Version S.O:', 
                App\SoVersiones::select(DB::raw("version AS version"), "id","id_so")->where('id_so', '=', 'resultado_primer_select')-> pluck('version', 'id','id_so')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

Así el segundo select solamente traera las versiónes del sistema operativo relacionado.